# How to create indices from elasticsearch data for paths in vega?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I am currently trying to create a node-graph in Kibana using vega following [this](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/force-directed-layout/) example. For testing I used a hardcoded example dataset for the `node-data` and `link-data` instead of the `data/miserables.json` .

**node-data values:**

```
[
   { "name": "node1" },
   { "name": "node2" }
]
```

**link-data values:**

```
[
   { "source": 0, "target": 1, "link-info": "connection" }
]
```

The `source` and `target` property of `link-data` expect the index of the corresponding `node-data` entry, so currently I draw two nodes with a hardcoded connection between *node1* and *node2* (works fine so far).

However, now I want to use data from an elasticsearch query instead of the hardcoded dataset.

At the moment I can query elasticsearch for a table in the following format

**elastic-data values:**

```
[
   { "src_node": "node1", "dst_node": "node2", "link_info": "connection" }
]
```

Now I don't know how to create the `link-data` from this. I could probably extract unique sources and destinations with an elasticsearch query to create the `node-data` but how could I get their index to create the matching `link-data`?

I found [this](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) `indexof()` function which I thought I could use in an `expr` to transform the `src_node`and `dst_node` but couldn't get it to work nor find examples on usage.

But maybe I miss another option, like maybe there is a way to use the `node.name` instead of the index for `source` and `target`?

---

I've put together a [**minimum working example**](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwAdgAMuxREgpG1fFoCs+w1ELo1axjOpaDSyOlZ5usRgC9kLUgZWUDFd19qGXQAG1gtAG0lCGAoaNRAnEh4AA8FKFZCNXQ8TJV1FjBSMAAmSDAAXxsUtPQMoPgAT3zIQuLSoJMzPCra+qbksFTgtrLg7jVkACV7RlZ4+SgKWNYymt1G5qnW9qyQxYBhRHQAJ2owrZ2ygFoAZgOJiBaZ06gYpwA1gARRiwPDoGTwB6QbYxXZaACM+ggny+03SczBJUY8B6sPhODwN12h0moC+X0giwQN0YhDwPDkWQAyuDSmBtrT0OwYsgwAAzbg3MDoeAMqhgc58-mMHJgLF4dZ0BSTIwYoIyvKbGFPLT82KwZBHIyyRKqtHmimQZBUGR4eJZWCdVDsbgxLCobjrZBevAJACENuQdro7C83hksAAuptVDI1NxlB6vYbCiqKRmCkUSnN9XFApbSZmUoWjEG7Q6oE6XW7k97uFQbuni0Y+jmNbKwAAfLtgInwwuozPkltQcv2oIJauu92e70J5QyWNOBd11OEKNgAB8YDjq7nhs9VH9zZbvWzAyyOU6AAoAJSn4uQQU3KFafvIQfmqOTIdTc1UsgNJ0gyppZAA4jc6CEIgkoLHynpgmANzIFCdoxJ0YBOKUUFisgai7swiDKsaJxzFKeK6jgMisDEMSkZAYFgEkLYjme46VpA061gePqNo+mbnv0uadgAvOJfbEnyAD8WGlKg95gNR8GQF+mY-hSf5sZS1LwLS9KMkEABiMToNQfbcMhQHgjcIxGUKULyowqC0dishgIU7n9OgYBIBC9ywCRAHqlkKFYrZlFwmUeaGgxTEscWwDWraE44ElkTRDEHZ5E0WbCdlYAAGSFQKsp0LyziaA036-koMYgO43lmhS2lqrMQRSs8TUMfiQHNYlZEdfBCLjKR3whWk8F1I0NWaUcrWDVk-wyACXUlJgPVPJWCXDlWXqvmUBhQDZ9x4Ii2rLatTiCh0sgyKhoFyDN6m-vNwXtVkyCmWCOJreCAlQLp+mPUEACqNGGgRJR9igYCehkIZgAAEomvkQmAACSVmEDcCysI5LB8vArA3ChdpWbAtEjPyuOoHBix-T5EIEZdjOEZULCgmA3mGng0kAzqUXbYW0ywK+AD6FFnMNPRqGCksqdLix1BdgLi9d3C3TI91ioZz0ZhpXzVRA9XuBgNwAsLLXvb88zUgLeCdIQmLOjOAt+CuyB5DgCLhIJNPcKgWhJU1SvIIzkB-iaTLMSLpbHbS1D3E2WSagDVqeo4-LdGH6eUr1nGamA4miZJJKycA-I5Mpix0DkmzZzXyB0J0DRKVMVc4JqCS6DGAqdF3soJAiUYNKpLZRxao4J6YydBP6adjZSmeMNnQ2LJFuycZX1eSrR9H99R+9j2pBt+xm1qQor-7sXayApzfo7PowdHB4LBJQNQKHdJPVpgrjAIyhJV6kEZQiBmCBGNsWX+eV2xpXjlxfwQDEFRFiEEGoYAABU9NlirHWFgnBKxHDrEjkvIwxMbjSAfsAqithuDYXvpHU+c0GqCSJBCWAL4g44B2hmBaVpHbOw1A5MICCIFQUepWd4bhp6QDCjZM6aUUGZSCPI24Z0YFGAVDiN+GU0GOjZDozRVZTAqNTiIvORgXxQittPKYz4LFZDQjhHo3t7F6Kyk4nK2oc7uNMfoqAXRI7GJSA4g6t06LqGhFBYhlZ0r+M8ZNRYRC1jxAaCE+x1jyKujUN0bU-9gzUE0Eojx69kBXFuPcYJZC0RhLfEtQEPRLqcVZt1QGoJwSQmQaUhpK0QRYi6cE+OhtMxQIpCMosU8L6CLmHYTQDEA7cPsaHP4gII6T0gAw3C4pooGiNABYM8Br78NgZeR+Z5-7cEAW-EBWQADE8BHmkIQZcwBAB1CoiAbm0N0HQCwYyMwApRAxdhkYuH9WHAgmZQRLpzK+TUuRyAACOrBGAoV0Qk4R4TjFcWuEI3pojZHSBJlCAAGkEforBUB0GJQdOuPRaVQgAJoUpKFSml+0oQt0scdSpyA8DkqyJS6lJ1+X0u1KKvALKhVspFXyvA3LmFfAmVAn81UgA) (Vega Online Editor) - **see line 69 for a short description**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles upon this: turns out i did miss this "another option".

It's as simple as appending `"id": "datum.name"` to

`{"force": "link", "links": "link-data", "distance": 100}`

so it looks like

`{"force": "link", "id": "datum.name", "links": "link-data", "distance": 100}`.

This allows name-based referencing instead of indices. Now the field `name` from the dataset `link-data` will be used to identify the item from `node-data`. [Documentation Reference](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/force/)